# Clarity of using if(count())

Tags: php, coding-style

In this code fragment:

```
$results = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($query);

if(count($results)) {
    // …
}
```

…do you consider the if(count()) part to be be a well understood idiom, or confusing code. i.e. should it be

```
if(count($results) > 0)
```

???

Comment: personally I always use the latter as its more informative and really, what do you actually gain a benefit for leaving the 4 characters out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a boolean expression with 'if' requires less understanding of a language than using implicit conversions, so I would always prefer the second option (adding "> 0") - at least if this code is meant to be read by others, too. You never know who will maintain your code. The keyword is "clarity" here.

But I must admit I have written many times code with if's using an int expression myself, too, because I like its elegance.

Comment: Thanks; it seems opinions are split on this one, but I think the most convincing argument is that you don't know who will maintain the code next.

Answer (score 1):

They are doing exactly the same job in this context, and are both easily readable.

I'll just add (just in case) that if you're performing this query only to `if(count())`, then you should be issuing a `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead!

Answer (score 1):

The `count` and the extraneous `>` comparison are pointless. If you receive an actualy `array`, then the test should just be:

```
 if ($results) {
```

That's what scripting languages are for. Abstracting low level details away.

You would only need the `count` if your fetchAll function returns an ArrayObject or similar. Should your function sometimes return a `false` for example, then your `if (count(` is going to fail (because `count(false)==1` in PHP).

Comment: Thanks, interesting details there. :)

Answer (score 0):

erm...not realy sure what the **purpose** of this question is - but the semantics should be self-evident to anyone whom understands PHP

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that the `> 0` check is redundant and unnecessary.

I know other developers who insist that it should be there for clarity, but frankly I can't why -- anyone who can read PHP should be able to discern that they are identical.

Comment: but what do you lose? it takes half a second to write and absolutely 100% guarantee's the clarity?

Comment: @Aleski - I don't see that there's any lack of clarity without it. That's my point.

Comment: if you do not have any doubts about the clarity, then why are you writing "should be able" instead of "is able" in your own answer? I think it is good "defensive programming" not to expect the next programmer to have the same sound knowledge as you.